# ResultConsumedException with Micronaut and Neo4j: Cannot access records on this result any more as the result has already been consumed

Tags: neo4j, micronaut

I'm attempting to get a simple app working with Micronaut 1.3.5 and Neo4J 4.0.0. I'm using the `io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-neo4j-bolt:2.0.0` driver. I have code like this:

```
public Stream<Map<String, Object>> findAll() {
   try (Session s = driver.session()) {
       String stmt = "MATCH (n:Product) RETURN n";
       return s.readTransaction(tx -> tx.run(stmt)).list(r -> r.asMap()).stream();
   }
}
```

And I'm getting the following exception:

```
result has already been consumed or the query runner where the result is created has already been closed.
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ResultConsumedException: Cannot access records on this result any more as the result has already been consumed or the query runner where the result is created has already been closed.
```

I've done some googling and found a few things that would suggest this is normal behavior, but nothing that discusses the actual solution. I'm assuming it has something to do with the async nature of the driver/session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that would work is,

```
Stream<Map<String, Object>> stream = s.readTransaction(tx -> {
    Result result = tx.run(stmt);
    return result.list(r -> r.asMap()).stream();
 });
```

The results need to be processed within the `readTransaction`

There are bunch of examples at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver/tree/4.1/examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/docs/driver which you may find useful

Comment: I don't get it then. How am I supposed to write a method for reading data in a repository class such that data can be iterated by the caller?

Comment: @AttilaSzeremi - did you ever find a solution to this? returning a stream for allowing your caller to iterate over it without running into Cannot access records on this result any more as the result has already been consumed error?

Comment: No. Sadly I gave up on this shortly afterwards, and we haven't made changes to the project since.

Comment: @AttilaSzeremi are you then evaluating result to list then converting back to stream as the other posted mentioned?